# Display and count qualifying data from a 2d array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, filtering, counting

I'm trying to count the number of times a certain value appears in my multidimensional array based on a condition. Here's an example array;

```
$fruit = [
    "oranges" => [
        "name"    => "Orange",
        "color"   => "orange",
        "taste"   => "sweet",
        "healthy" => "yes"
    ],
    "apples" => [
        "name"    => "Apple",
        "color"   => "green",
        "taste"   => "sweet",
        "healthy" => "yes"
    ],
    "bananas" => [
        "name"    => "Banana",
        "color"   => "yellow",
        "taste"   => "sweet",
        "healthy" => "yes"
    ],
    "grapes" => [
        "name"    => "Grape",
        "color"   => "green",
        "taste"   => "sweet",
        "healthy" => "yes"
    ]
];
```

If I want to display all `green` coloured fruit, I can do the following (let me know if this is the best way of doing it):

```
for ($row = 0; $row < 3; $row++) {
    if($fruit[$row]["color"]=="green") {
         echo $fruit[$row]["name"] . '<br />';
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
Apple
Grape
```

That's great and I can see their are 2 values there, but how can I actually get PHP to count the number of fruit where the colour is `green` and put it in a variable for me to use further down the script to work stuff out?

I want to do something like;

```
if ($number_of_green_fruit > 1) {
    echo "You have more than 1 piece of green fruit";
}
```

I've taken a look at `count()`, but I don't see any way to add conditional logic to that function call.

Comment: Instead of echo'ing the name, do the count. 0 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 ....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$number_of_green_fruit = 0;
for ($row = 0; $row < 3; $row++) {
    if($fruit[$row]["color"]=="green") {
         $number_of_green_fruit++;
         echo $fruit[$row]["name"] . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: In modern PHP versions, you can use array destructuring inside of a `foreach()` loop like [this](https://3v4l.org/oI5jn).

Answer (score 14):

PHP has no support for a `SQL where` sort of thing, especially not with an array of arrays. But you can do the counting your own while you iterate over the data:

```
$count = array();
foreach($fruit as $one)
{
    @$count[$one['color']]++;
}

printf("You have %d green fruit(s).\n", $count['green']);
```

The alternative is to write yourself some little helper function:

```
/**
 * array_column
 *
 * @param array $array rows - multidimensional
 * @param int|string $key column
 * @return array;
 */
function array_column($array, $key) {
    $column = array();
    foreach($array as $origKey => $value) {
        if (isset($value[$key])) {
            $column[$origKey] = $value[$key];
        }            
    }
    return $column;
}
```

You then can get all colors:

```
$colors = array_column($fruit, 'color');
```

And then count values:

```
$count = array_count_values($colors);
printf("You have %d green fruit(s).\n", $count['green']);
```

That kind of helper function often is useful for multidimensional arrays. It is also [suggested as a new PHP function for PHP 5.5](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/array_column).

Answer (score 5):

All you need is an extra counter:

```
for ($row = $number_of_green_fruit = 0; $row < 3; $row++) {
    if($fruit[$row]["color"]=="green") {
         echo $fruit[$row]["name"] . '<br />';
         $number_of_green_fruit++;
    }
}

if($number_of_green_fruit > 1) {
    echo "You have more than 1 piece of green fruit";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With PHP 5.4+ you can have this short snippet to count specific values (don't even need to declare the `$count` variable previously)

```
array_walk_recursive($fruit, function ($value) use (&$count) {
    $count += (int) ($value === 'green');
});

var_dump($count); // Outputs: int(2)
```