# PHP - count specific array values

Tags: php, arrays, count

How can I count the number of element inside an array with value equals a constant?
example,

```
$myArray = array("Kyle","Ben","Sue","Phil","Ben","Mary","Sue","Ben");
```

how can I directly know how many "Ben" is inside?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

```
$array = array("Kyle","Ben","Sue","Phil","Ben","Mary","Sue","Ben");
$counts = array_count_values($array);
echo $counts['Ben'];
```

Comment: what if the array is multidimensional?

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi then OP needs to update the question.

Comment: @James Can you please give me a reference ?

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi:  First SO result I found on google: [Count specific values in multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558397/count-specific-values-in-multidimensional-array/11558780) - see if that works for multidimensionals.

Comment: @cullub it works for 2 levels depth. if the array is deeper, we have to add more iteration. I made it by building recursive function.

Comment: Nice.  Just posting that link for future Googlers who are looking for a multidimensional solution.

Comment: if you count element which is not in array, it will show `Notice: Undefined index`

Comment: @Elyor do you know how I can fix this?? In my case I need to output 4 variables for some javascript. I already tested with `isset($codes['T'])? $codes['T']:'' ` where $codes is the = array_count_values(

Comment: For float values get this: `Warning: array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!` what's solution?

Answer (score 43):

You can do this with *array_keys* and *count*.

```
$array = array("blue", "red", "green", "blue", "blue");
echo count(array_keys($array, "blue"));
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: This is the best answer because it doesn't bother php to count all occurrences of all values, it just returns the qualifying keys and counts them in a way which will never throw a `Notice`. In other words, `echo count(array_keys($array, "purple"));` prints `0` with no `Notice` This is a superior / cleaner approach versus `array_count_values()`. +1

Comment: I tested this code vs the code @Rajat Singhal posted. [PHP-Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aee8e6a978c45a3369fd60984ad4da3244812bfe). In PHP 7 the `count(array_keys())` solution always is faster. In PHP 5.6 the `array_count_values()` version is faster for arrays with less different elements. All in all both functions are quite fast (at least for the arrays I was testing)

Comment: IMO this is the best answer also because it works with arrays containing values other than strings and integers whereas `array_count_values()` would complain about it. +1

Answer (score 18):

To count a value in a two dimensional array, here is the useful snippet **to process and get count of a particular value**-

```php
    <?php
    
    $list = [
      ['id' => 1, 'userId' => 5],
      ['id' => 2, 'userId' => 5],
      ['id' => 3, 'userId' => 6],
    ];

    $userId = 5;
    
    echo array_count_values(array_column($list, 'userId'))[$userId]; // outputs: 2
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) function.

$countValues = array_count_values($myArray);

`echo $countValues["Ben"];`

Answer (score 6):

Use `array_count_values()` function . Check this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: I know that but does not gives what I want, it returns all the number of same element

Comment: @ivory-santos are you sure this method is not helpful ??..check this link http://codepad.org/Ye2x8uQD

Comment: @ivory-santos isn't it what you exactly want?

Comment: not really :) i got the answer, i don't know lately that after counting it is possible to count['Ben']. thanks

Comment: @ivory-santos all good :) it happens (at least from my programming experience ..lol)

Answer (score 5):

```
define( 'SEARCH_STRING', 'Ben' );

$myArray = array("Kyle","Ben","Sue","Phil","Ben","Mary","Sue","Ben");

$count = count(array_filter($myArray,function($value){return SEARCH_STRING === $value;}));

echo $count, "\n";
```

Output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 2):

try the array_count_values() function

```
<?php
$array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Answer (score 1):

Try the PHP function [`array_count_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count ALL the same occurences inside the array, here's a function to count them all, and return the results as a multi-dimensional array:

```
function countSame($array) {

$count = count($array);
$storeArray = array();
while ($count > 0) {
$count--;

if ($array[$count]) {
$a = $array[$count];
$counts = array_count_values($array);
$counts = $counts[$a];
$tempArray = array($a, $counts);
array_push($storeArray, $tempArray);

$keys = array_keys($array, $a);
foreach ($keys as $k) {
unset($array[$k]);
} //end of foreach ($keys as $k)
} //end of if ($array[$count])

} //end of while ($count > 0)

return $storeArray;

} //end of function countSame($array)
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_count_values` only works for integers and strings. If you happen to want counts for float/numeric values (and you are heedless of small variations in precision or representation), this works:

```
function arrayCountValues($arr) {
  $vals = [];
  foreach ($arr as $val) { array_push($vals,strval($val)); }
  $cnts = array_count_values($vals);
  arsort($cnts);
  return $cnts;
}
```

Note that I return `$cnts` with the keys as strings. It would be easy to reconvert them, but I'm trying to determine the **mode** for the values, so I only need to re-convert the first (several) values.

I tested a version which looped, creating an array of counts rather than using `array_count_values`, and this turned out to be more efficient (by maybe 8-10%)!