# How can echo in php array count each value

Tags: php, arrays

how can echo count of each value in php array? for example in this array:

```
 $array = array(test,test,ok,test,ok);
```

now how can echo count test or ok in this array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646054/php-count-specific-array-values

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Example straight from the official PHP.net

```
<?php
$array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>

Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)
```

If you want to echo then throw that command in.

For your example:

```
<?php
    $array = array(test,test,ok,test,ok); 
    print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [test] => 3
    [ok] => 2
)
```

To echo try a foreach loop or something like this:

```
echo "Test = ".array_count_values($array)['test'];
```

The output is:

```
Test = 3
```

Comment: array_count_values? :O Nice!

Comment: this $array is only test i have many value in my $array and i want know count each value in my array

Answer (score 1):

simple way:

```
print_r(array_count_values($array));
```

if you want just the "ok":

```
echo array_count_values($array)['ok'] // output 2
```