# Count total JSON value for only a specific key

Tags: php, json

i have this kind of problem. Below is my code,

```
$json = json_decode($result, true);
echo '<pre>';
foreach($json['campaigns'] as $campaign)
{
    print_r(array('campaign_id'=>$campaign['id'],
    'campaign_name'=>$campaign['settings']['title'],
    'emails_sent'=>$campaign['emails_sent']));
}
$sum = array('emails_sent'=>$campaign['emails_sent']);
print_r('Total Email Sent: ' . array_sum($sum));
exit();
```

and the output is like below,

```
Array
(
    [campaign_id] => bb50c7bb13
    [campaign_name] => Campaign #1
    [emails_sent] => 3
)
Array
(
    [campaign_id] => 6b8194db96
    [campaign_name] => Campaign #2
    [emails_sent] => 4
)
Array
(
    [campaign_id] => be9f2aed3e
    [campaign_name] => Campaign #3
    [emails_sent] => 0
)
Array
(
    [campaign_id] => eb48c292cb
    [campaign_name] => Campaign Scheduler #4
    [emails_sent] => 0
)
Total Email Sent: 0
```

As you can see, i want to count total number for ['emails_sent']. So for my case, the total value for ['emails_sent'] is 7. Why the output shows 0?

Comment: just use `array_count_values()` to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - count specific array values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646054/php-count-specific-array-values)

Comment: @FrayneKonok i tried use array_count_values() it return array. i use the solution from Fabio and it is working. btw, thanks for help. got new knowledge :)

Comment: You got your desire answer, so be happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just sum your email sent while iterating

```
$json = json_decode($result, true);
$sum = 0;
echo '<pre>';
foreach($json['campaigns'] as $campaign) {
    print_r(array('campaign_id'=>$campaign['id'],
    'campaign_name'=>$campaign['settings']['title'],
    'emails_sent'=>$campaign['emails_sent']));    
    $sum += $campaign['emails_sent'];
}
print_r('Total Email Sent: ' . $sum);
//print Total Email Sent: 7
exit();
```