# How to output repeat strings with looping and explode method only

Tags: php, string, loops, repeat

e.g. "I think I got a long way to go to market."

In this case, I want to output

```
I 2
think 1
got 1
a 1
long 1
way 1
to 2
go 1
market 1
```

Code:

```
<?php
$tmp = explode (" ", $text);
    echo "
         
        My Words
        Repetition
        ";
        
         foreach ($tmp as $a)
        {
            
            echo "" $a."" ;
            echo ""  ;
        }       
        echo ""
?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - count specific array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646054/php-count-specific-array-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with

```
$text = "I think I got a long way to go to market.";
$tmp = explode (" ", $text);
foreach($tmp as $a){
   $result[$a] += 1;
}
foreach($result as $value => $occurrences){
   echo "$value $occurrences\n";
}
```