# Php count conditions inside loop

Tags: php, loops, count

**Close my question when it´sdifferent to this not duplicater, the case it´s different in all :
[PHP - count specific array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646054/php-count-specific-array-values)
My question not the same**

**I have this array for example :**

```
$array_test=array("gren","green","red","red","green","blue");
```

My idea is know inside loop number of elementos with the condition i want, the array for show it´s more complex and this is only example for understand i need, because try different ways with "count" and don´t show right this number in each case.

**I try this :**

```
foreach($array_test as $array_ts) {

if($array_ts=="green") { Count number of elements green /// }

if($array_ts=="red") { Count number of elements red /// }

if($array_ts=="blue") { Count number of elements blue /// }

}
```

**Thank´s for the help, regards.**

Answer (score -2):

You can create an array and fill it with the count for each color:

```
$input = ["gren","green","red","red","green","blue"];

$count = [];

foreach ($input as $color) {
   if (array_key_exists($color, $count)) {
       $count[$color]++;
   } else {
       $count[$color] = 1;
   }
}
```

`$count` will contain:

```
["green"=>3, "red"=>2, "blue"=>1]
```

Comment: `$input` is not an array though

Comment: No works, give me error

Comment: I missed typing the array brackets. Now it's right.

Comment: I missed typing the array brackets. Now it's right.