# PHP get a part of a array using function

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$a1 = array(
    array('id'=>"1","others"=>"asdhuisah"),
    array('id'=>"4","others"=>"asdhuisah"),
    array('id'=>"213","others"=>"asdhuisah")
);
```

and I want to save a part of it into a new array `$a2`.

I know I can do it using loops:

```
$a2 = array();
foreach($a1 as $key=>$value){
    array_push($a2,$value["id"]);
}
```

Is there a function that I can use to do all this at once?

Comment: Did you check here? http://fr.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: The function you are looking for is called [`array_column`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11558780/367456).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$fun_id = function($value){

    return $value["id"];

} ;

$a2 = array_map($fun_id, $a1);
```

Comment: thanks your code does work. I mean is there a function in PHP, not user definded function.

Comment: @v-joy The answer to that question is simply "no" at this point in time.

Comment: No, there is no such built-in function. As mentioned in the thread hakre linked to, it has been proposed for PHP 5.5.

Comment: there is not, but that way is clean and elegant.

Comment: Array_slice can do it I think

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_map and a lambda function:

```
$return_id = function($item) {
  return $item['id'];
};
$ids_array = array_map($return_id, $a1);
```

Comment: I am wondering if there is a buildin function witch can do this job. but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think array_slice http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php can do it for you.