# How to properly use array_walk() function to count specific values in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I can't sleep well with this one problem. I couldn't find other solution. I have tried some functions, but I can't achieve desirable result with those. So one guy told me to use `array_walk()`. Yes this function does what I want, but i can't or i don't know how to properly insert it in my code.

My PHP code:

```
$d=array();
foreach(range(0, 3) as $rs) {
    foreach(range(0, 5) as $c){

        //here is working php code to generate '$randomRs' by '$rs' and '$c' vars..

        $d['rs'.$rs]['c'.$c] = $randomRs;

    }
}
```

Generated JSON output:

```
{
"rs0":{
   "c0":"pl",
   "c1":"wd",
   "c2":"wd",
   "c3":"pl",
   "c4":"bl"
},
"rs1":{
   "c0":"gr",
   "c1":"gr",
   "c2":"lk",
   "c3":"gr",
   "c4":"lk"
}
and so on...
```

All i need is one simple code to count specific values of that array.
For example: i need to count how many "wd" and "lk" there is in array. Guy told me to use `array_walk()`, but i am new with those array's and i really need some advise!

Comment: Why would it matter what function you use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count specific values in multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558397/count-specific-values-in-multidimensional-array)

Comment: @miken32 I have tried those in that thread, but i need to search by value, not by key..

Comment: @jeroen dunno. All i need is to count key values. That's it. He told me that I can use `array_walk()` for that.

Comment: Count in the entire array or each sub array separately?

Comment: Another way is to use `randomRs` as the index into an array and keep a count for each value? see: https://eval.in/728697

Comment: @RyanVincent thanks man! Thats what i was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your loop just use:

```
$temp[] = $randomRs;
```

Then you can count them easily:

```
$count = array_count_values($temp);
echo $count['wd'];
```