# Create variable inside/after if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

In JSON with key "string" and "value":

```
'Something xxx something' = 10
'Something yyy something' = 20
'Something xxx something' = 30
'Something zzz something' = 40
```

The flow I want is:

```
find partial string inside string
if true
get sum of all its matched string's value
if false
return 0
```

What I tried is

```
if (strpos($string, 'xxx') == false){
        $value = array_sum(array_column($arrayjson['string'],'value'));
        continue;
    }
echo $value
```

But, what I am getting is

```
100
100
```

Expected result is `40`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4979238/2943403

Comment: Found this before, but not really explain my problem. Nigel's answer explained well what my mistake was.

Comment: Please clarify your input.  You say that it is json, but is clearly not json.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558397/count-specific-values-in-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that even though you check if the string contains `xxx` (BTW you should use `!== false` as it may return `0`), you then use `array_column()` to extract all of the values and add them all up(which is why you get 100).

This loops over the data and adds only the rows that match your required string...

```
$data = [ ['string' => 'Something xxx something', 'value' => 10],
    ['string' => 'Something yyy something', 'value'  => 20],
    ['string' => 'Something xxx something', 'value'  => 30],
    ['string' => 'Something zzz something', 'value'  => 40]];

$total = 0;
foreach ( $data as $row )   {
    if (strpos($row['string'], 'xxx') !== false){
        $total += $row['value'];
    }
}
echo $total;
```

Comment: Thank you Nigel. Actually I stumbled upon `foreach` before, but not working because my `if (strpos...` was actually inside another `for ($j = 0; $j < ...` loop function. But your explanation give me a bigger picture of my mistake; to replace my loop function with `foreach`. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

At a cost of more function calls and a minor drop in efficiency, you can avoid the use of temporary variables by nesting native functions. (I'd use Nigel's way though)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IXiia))

```
echo array_sum(
         array_column(
             array_filter(
                 $arrayjson,
                 function($row) {
                     return strpos($row['string'], 'xxx') !== false;
                 }
             ),
             'value'
         )
     );
```